# Background color fom database ASP/MySQL

Tags: mysql, asp-classic

I am trying to have my asp-classic pages display the background color based on the six digit hex value sent TO mysql db via js color picker.  I am able to display images, but not colors.  Here is my little snippet.

body {background-color: url(<%=(Recordset1.Fields.Item("bg_color").Value)%>);}

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's customary to accept an answer if it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

just remove the url(..) thing as you want a color you do not need the url()...

like so:

```
body {background-color: <%=(Recordset1.Fields.Item("bg_color").Value)%>;}
```